# how to fetch data in angular js that is sent as json response from node js (express js middle ware)

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, node.js, cookies

So I'm working on tokens that I am making manually. What I want to do is after user logins a token is sent to angular module in json format or some other format doesn't matter and then I'd like to save it in a cookie.

Here is a simple json response code from node js

```
res.json({success : 1, token: "adhahashahd"});
```

please guide me now how to fetch this in angular controller and then how to save this in angular cookie.

Thanks.

> This is the edited part guys

This is my controller's code which calls node js route

```
    $http.post('../userlogin', $scope.user).success(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
```

This is the response which is made by nodejs after the whole process is complete

```
res.json({token : "asx"});
```

Now this is the cookie part which I followed from the answers given below.

```
    $http.post('../userlogin', $scope.user).success(function(response) {
    console.log(response);




   $http.get('userlogin').success(function(data){
    data=JSON.Parse(data); 
   $cookie.put('token',data.token)
    }).error(function(error){
    console.log(error)
    })
```

The error comes on the front end part, as seen in developer window of google chrome

```
GET http://localhost:1339/userlogin 404 (Not Found)
```

> Up voted all of you, thanks guys. One question if all answers are good enough can I accept multiple answers. Because all you guys gave correct suggestion.

I am really thankful. :)

> Edit no 2 guys

When  I am simply doing this

```
var z = response.token; 
      console.log(z);
      $cookie.put('token', z);
```

I am able to get what I wanted but the error is related to cookie now.

It reads

```
ReferenceError: $cookie is not defined
    at controller.js:35
    at angular.js:9369
    at angular.js:13189
    at l.c.$get.l.$eval (angular.js:14401)
    at l.c.$get.l.$digest (angular.js:14217)
    at l.c.$get.l.$apply (angular.js:14506)
    at l (angular.js:9659)
    at P (angular.js:9849)
    at XMLHttpRequest.w.onload (angular.js:9790)
```

fetching the data is done, although not by the method you guys suggested. What I am doing is right or not conventionally? Please let me know with reasons that will help me to understand the topic in a better manner.

Thanks

> Last Edit

The cookie problem I mentioned above is solved, it was simply because I had forgotten to use the store word along with it.

The code you guys gave me, I have nothing against it but things just worked simply for me. It may be wrong conventionally because of things which I don't understand probably.

That is why I request you guys to further add anything if necessary.

Thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I would like to thank all the people who have helped me along the way.

And without any disrespect to people who have answered, I am answering this question with different answer that worked.

Here is the format in which the data is being sent from the server as response, which is also given in the question posted above.

```
res.json({token : "asx"});
```

This is the code for angular JS controller.

The code is working properly according to my needs and it is working like a charm.

```
      var z = response.token; 
      $cookieStore.put('token', z);
      var f = $cookieStore.get('token');
```

Answer (score 1):

Call the nodejs API which sent this token in angularjs

To call the nodejs API from angularjs use angular `$http` module and if your node API are RestAPI then use `$resource` for better control over API calls.

Example :

```
$http.get('apicall');
```

Comment: Yes I'm working with RESTapi. Can you please give a practical example.

Comment: well google search took me to useless tutorials and useless stackoverflow questions.

Answer (score 1):

Assumning you have a controller set up, you would simply have to make a call with the `$http` call.

`$http.get(URL)` would make the call via GET method, `$http.post(url)` would make it a POST.

After that, to get the data you need to use promises that $http returns.I've never used the `$cookies` service but it seems straightforward enough:

```
$http.get(URL).success(function(data){
    $cookie.put('token',data.token)
}).error(function(error){
    console.log(error)
})
```

I would strongly recommend reading the [AngularJS tutorial](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_00) to learn a little more about the `$http` service, promises and how to handle them.

Comment: thanks for your help. what exactly the URL has to be because I posted 'userLogin', and this is the link where I sent the control to using the post command to node js part, where everything was handled and then a response comes from that end.

Comment: Well, I can't say, I don't know your setup. Usually you set up a route in your node app where the data is sent to and in return it will spit out the JSON response you gave on your initial question.

You can try both relative and absolute URLs. Check the network panel to see what you're sending, where, and what the response is (including http status, such as a 404)

Comment: Also keep in mind that there's different methods for $http, if your route was set up as POST, then you should use $http.post() instead of $http.get()

Comment: I have just posted a code which is working perfectly. Please let me know is it okay to code it like that or if it is wrong conventionally. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Consider you have a API and it returns a `json` serialized object.

**In Angular Controller:**

```
 $http.get("ur Api Url or path").then(function(data){
   //data will hold json result
  // First parse the "data" variable like data=JSON.parse(data);
  // Then you can save it to cookie or use angularjs  Value
  ....
  }).error(function(error){
 ...
  });
```

Comment: I think you got error because of capital P in JSON.Parse, Actually it is small case like shown below JSON.parse

Comment: ohh I get it. Can you please check the answer I have written and let me know if it is okay conventionally to work that way.